# WMTS request with brutile and sharp map return wrong parameter

Tags: geoserver, c#, vb.net, wmts, sharpmap

I'm using brutile and sharpmap to send wmts request and show maps.
here is my code:

```
    Public Shared Function Create() As ITileSource
    Dim uri As New Uri("http://91.98.30.14:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=getcapabilities&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&TILED=true")
    Dim req As Object = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    Dim resp As Object = req.GetResponseAsync()
    Dim tileSource As ITileSource
    Using stream As Object = resp.Result.GetResponseStream()
        Dim tileSources As List(Of ITileSource)
        tileSources = WmtsParser.Parse(stream)
        tileSource = tileSources.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "CH") '
    End Using
    Return tileSource
End Function
```

first of all, it is very slow to response and second, WmtsParser.parse returns "layer title" parameter for "layer name", and for "layer name" it returns "layer projection" to tileSources!
why do those issues happen?

Comment: Could you add the wmts capabilities you get as response?

Comment: @pauldendulk, I suppose you can get the xml file by clicking on the link below: http://91.98.30.14:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=getcapabilities&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&TILED=true

Comment: @pauldendulk, did you get the xml file? what do you think about that? can i just send WMTS request to geoserver without fetching xml capabilities?